# How to deploy a Tornado service behind an Apache2 Virtual Host?

Tags: python, apache, tornado

I have a Python script with Tornado, I'm running my program on port 8088 like this:

```
http://144.44.44.44:8088/web
```

Now, I want to map to port number 80 and run this script like this:

```
http://144.44.44.44/web
```

I'm using Centos7 with apache and httpd services.

I tried to create a virtual server but couldn't config success!

I created config file:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName  web.whisla.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://144.44.44.44:8088/web
    ProxyPassReverse / http://144.44.44.44:8088/web

    ErrorLog /opt/whisla/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /opt/whisla/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

also I have config directory in

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/
/etc/httpd/conf/
```

but don't know how is going there!

How I can config this Tornado with apache server?